# How does ASP.NET Core Web API build URLs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have the following code:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MarketReportInstancesTableController : BaseController
{
    internal readonly MyIRIntegrationDbContext Context;

    public MarketReportInstancesTableController(ILogger<MarketReportInstancesTableController> logger,
        MyIRIntegrationDbContext context) : base(logger)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet (Name ="PageData")]
    public IActionResult PageData([FromQuery] IDataTablesRequest request)
    {
    .... methd body in here
    }
```

And I try to access with a URL like:

```
http://somehost/pca/api/MarketReportInstancesTable/pagedata
```

Which DOES NOT work, but

```
http://somehost/pca/api/MarketReportInstancesTable/
```

DOES WORK.

My question would be, why does the route do that? I want to have many paths in the same WebAPI controller.

Am I approaching it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no route template in the route. You only have a route name

> Route names can be used to generate a URL based on a specific route. **Route names have no impact on the URL matching behavior of routing and are only used for URL generation.** Route names must be unique application-wide.

*emphasis mine*

```
//GET api/MarketReportInstancesTable/pagedata
[HttpGet ("pagedata", Name ="PageData")]
public IActionResult PageData([FromQuery] IDataTablesRequest request) {
    //.... methd body in here
}
```

Using `[HttpGet]` without a route template is the same as `[HttpGet("")]` which will map to the root of the controller with route prefix.

This explains why your root call works.

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: Ahh so perfect, I had just convinced myself I didn't need that!